# Php change color one cell text from stored proc

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, colors

I use sql server stored proc where one column send me information about color, but i need to apply it one an other column but more exactly on one cell and not the complete row. For now, what i can do it's on the row only and i need to do it exclusively on the red one. Here's my code for now :

```
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //print_r( $row );  // debug code
    $couleur='black';
    $font= 'normal';
    $font2= '#transparent';
    if( strstr($row['HTML_CODE'], "BOLD()")){
        $font= 'bold';
    }
    if( strstr($row['HTML_CODE'], "BG()")){
        $font2= '#D8D8D8';
    }
    if( strstr($row['HTML_CODE'], "RED()")){
        $couleur='red';
    }   
?>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php echo "<tr style=\"font-weight:$font; color:$couleur; background-color:$font2;\">"; ?>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['TextLine']);?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalQty']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalQty'],0,'',' ');?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalAmountDrawer']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalAmountDrawer'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalAmountPickup']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalAmountPickup'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalAmountOverShort']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalAmountOverShort'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
<?php
}  
 ?>
```

I need to apply it on the column name  : TotalAmountOverShort only!

Thank you for your help, it's really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS `color` rule from `TR` to `TD`.
If the background color also applies to only one cell, do the same with `background-color`:

```
 <tr>
 <?php echo "<tr style=\"font-weight:$font; background-color:$font2;\">"; ?>
    <td><?php echo ($row['TextLine']);?></td>
    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalQty']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalQty'],0,'',' ');?></td>
    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalAmountDrawer']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalAmountDrawer'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>
    <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalAmountPickup']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalAmountPickup'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>
    <td style="text-align: right; color: <?php echo $couleur; ?>"><?php echo is_null($row['TotalAmountOverShort']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['TotalAmountOverShort'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>
</tr>
```